# Визуализация работы модели

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, визуализация

Никак не могу разобраться с визуализацией работы модели. Написал код, который обучает модель и визуализирует её работу (картинку прикрепляю). Но я хочу нарисовать точно такую же виуализацию, но при этом обучать модель с использованием PolynomialFeatures. Однако когда я применяю этот метод на данные, количество фичей увеличивается и график не получается нарисовать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как нарисовать точно такую же картинку, но предварительно применив для данных PolynomialFeatures.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код для обычного графика выглядит примерно так

```
l = .02
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min(), X[:, 0].max()
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min(), X[:, 1].max()
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, l),
                            np.arange(y_min, y_max, l))

cm = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#0000FF'])
plt.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train, cmap=cm)
plt.scatter(X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c=y_test, cmap=cm, alpha=0.6)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[XX.ravel(), YY.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(XX.shape)
plt.contourf(XX, YY, Z, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu, alpha=.8)
plt.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train, cmap=cm)
plt.scatter(X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c=y_test, cmap=cm,
                      alpha=0.6)
```

Что изменить, чтобы можно было применить PolynomialFeatures?

Comment: Покажите ваш код. Вы можете обучить модель на дополнительных фичах, а визуализацию делать по исходным столбцам и полученному предсказанию

Comment: Код добавлен в вопрос.

Comment: Приведите весь код - подключение библиотек, загрузку данных. А то мне сложновато будет воспроизвести нормально

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку автор вопроса код пока не предоставил, опишу "на пальцах".

Вот у вас есть исходные данные `X` с двумя колонками, `y`, ну и `y_predict` как результат работы модели. По двум координатам из `X` и цвету из `y` строится `scatter plot`, по тем же двум координатам из `X` и по `y_predict` (вернее по `predict_proba` либо по `decision_function`, но это уже детали реализации) рисуются `decision boundaries`.

Теперь вы хотите применить `PolynomialFeatures`. Отлично, вы применяете их к `X`, получаете некий `X1` со множеством фич, тренируете модель, получаете новое предсказание `y1_predict`. И теперь вы рисуете всё тоже самое, что и раньше по тем же данным, что и раньше (по исходным `X` и `y`), только у вас будет другой `y1_predict`, по которому вы нарисуете немного другие `decision boundaries`, вот и всё. Рисовать лишние "координаты", которые у вас образовались после применения `PolynomialFeatures` - не нужно. Хотя если у вас данные очень плохо разделяются - вот в этом случае можете попробовать просто попарно перебрать все столбцы из `X1` и нарисовать с ними такой же график. Возможно (но не обязательно) какой-то из этих графиков окажется более информативным, с более лучшим разделением таргета. Это можно попробовать. Но в любом случае нарисовать график сразу во всём многомерном пространстве у вас не получится.

Впрочем, есть ещё варианты. Можно при желании нарисовать трёхмерный график - `matplotlib` это умеет. И можно "растащить" многомерные данные на две координаты с помощью `PCA` либо, лучше, `t-SNE` и нарисовать график уже в этих, преобразованных координатах. Вопрос в том - какая цель этого всего и нужно ли вам это.

Comment: Код добавлен в вопрос.

Comment: @Victor Ну, всё будет как я описал, только надо тщательно всё сделать. Приведёте остальную часть кода - переделаю его под ваши нужды. Хотя бы с загрузкой стандартного датасета сделайте, обычно на `iris` делают, например